# Firebase Hosting on own server

Tags: firebase, chat, firebase-hosting

I am looking for a solution for developing iOS and Android chat to replace our current (unreliable, maybe poorly written by previous devs) XMPP/OpenFire chat. I came across Firebase which looks good. However, I don't quite get the setup for it.

Can I host Firebase on my own server and not have to subscribe to any of Firebase's plans?

Comment: you can, but it will be substantially more expensive as it is their enterprise solution. hosting on your premises is optional.

Comment: Hosting on your own premises is not currently optional.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firebase offers a few products:

- the Firebase realtime database
- Firebase hosting (for hosting static resources)
- Firebase authentication

I think you are looking for the Firebase realtime database.

There is no way currently to host the Firebase realtime database on your own servers.

Comment: Yes Im looking for the Firebase real time database. So I was wondering if I can host it via Firebase Hosting to avoid subscription. Your answer has made it clear that I cannot host the realtime database on my own server. But is the Firebase Hosting like any other website hosting services or does it offer any new technology or advantage?

Comment: *disclaimer: I work for Firebase, so this comment maybe somewhat tainted* There is nothing about Firebase Hosting, that another web host can't also provide. You can definitely host your HTML/JS/CSS on any provider and access the data in Firebase's database from it. The biggest advantages of Firebase Hosting are probably that it's free and the simplicity of `firebase deploy`.

Comment: What about https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup ? Would this allow us to save the data on our own servers?

Answer (score 6):

Probably to late to be of any help but an alternative is RethinkDb. It is an open source realtime database and can be installed on your own machines.
Never used it myself just researching my options like you.

Comment: Unfortunately, RethinkDB has been shut down: https://rethinkdb.com/blog/rethinkdb-shutdown/

Comment: not dead:  https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/02/07/rethinkdb_lands_license_to_live/